# simple log in method

Tags: android, passwords

I making my own app and i want to set a Password for it (my password is ABC). When i type Password to editText if `Password  = ABC` my app auto on else Password # ABC try again. Please help me do that!
I tried this method but it has error. The error is when i input Password wrong and delete it so my app is forced close.

```
class mythread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i = 0;
        while (i == 0) {
            if (edit.getText().toString().equals(ABC)) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        }
    }
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

.....

```
mythread thread = new mythread();
    Thread td = new Thread(thread);
    try {
        td.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    td.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really need to be threaded for the set uo you described. Take a look at SharedPreferences and check whether or not a value has been saved on the screen before the login page, or even in the onCreate of the activity of the log in page.